# Question about a countable family of infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: set-theory

Assume CH. Show that given a countable family {$A_n|n\in \mathbb{N}$} of infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, show that there is a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{N}$ such that $S$ intersects each $A_n$, but contains none of them.
I tried to construct such $S$ by induction. It's fine when the family is finite, but once I take Union over $n$, $S$ may become too large. I don't know how to solve it. Is it related to Martin 's Axiom or somethindg like that? Because CH implies MA. But I don't know.

Comment: CH? Is this the axiom of choice?

Comment: @ncmathsadist CH refers to the Continuum Hypothesis: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Work in stages. Let $A_i=\{a_n^i: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Build $S$ as follows:

- Put $a_0^0$ in $S$, keep $a_1^0$ out of $S$.
- Let $n$ be the least such that $a_n^1>a_1^0$. Put $a_n^1$ in $S$, keep $a_{n+1}^1$ out of $S$.
- Do you see how to keep going?

Note that this doesn't use CH - unless I'm missing something, that's not necessary.

Comment: I think it works, thank you! How did you come up with this? I have been thinking of this problem with no progress...

Comment: @user323507 Break the problem into a set of simple *requirements*, which you can then satisfy in a sequence of *stages*. Our "big" requirements here are: $S$ intersects each $A_i$, but doesn't contain any $A_i$. Broken into simple requirements, this gives: **positive requirements** "there is some $x\in A_i$ which is in $S$" and **negative requirements** "there is some $x\in A_i$ which is not in $S$. We then try to satisfy these one at a time: positive requirement for $i=0$, then negative for $i=0$, then positive for $i=1$, then negative for $i=1$, etc. Does this help?

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much!